# Build spring integration release strategy using spring DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am new to Spring integration. I am trying to split the message from a file using file splitter and then use .aggregate() to build a single message and send to output channel.
I have markers as true and hence apply-sequence is false by default now.
I have set correlationId to a constant "1" using enrichHeaders. I have trouble setting the realease strategy as I do not have a hold on the sequence end. Here is how my code looks.

```
    IntegrationFlows
                .from(s -> s.file(new File(fileDir))
                                .filter(getFileFilter(fileName)),
                        e -> e.poller(poller))

                .split(Files.splitter(true, true)
                                .charset(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII),
                        e -> e.id(beanName)).enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("correlationId", "1"));

 IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = integrationFlowBuilder
            .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m -> m
                    .channelMapping(FileSplitter.FileMarker.class, "markers.input")
                    .channelMapping(String.class, "lines.input"))
            .get();

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow itemExcludes() {
        return flow -> flow.transform(new ItemExcludeRowMapper(itemExcludeRowUnmarshaller)) //This maps each line to ItemExclude object
                .aggregate(aggregator -> aggregator
                        .outputProcessor(group -> group.getMessages()
                        .stream()
                        .map(message -> ((ItemExclude) message.getPayload()).getPartNumber())
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","))))
                .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                .channel(customSource.itemExclude());
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow itemExcludeMarkers() {
        return flow -> flow
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO)
                .<FileSplitter.FileMarker>filter(m -> m.getMark().equals(FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END))
                .<FileHandler>handle(new FileHandler(configProps))
                .channel(NULL_CHANNEL);
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom release strategy that looks for the END marker in the last message and, perhaps, a custom output processor that removes the markers from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

I would move your header enricher for the `correlationId` before `splitter` and make it like this:

```
 .enrichHeaders(h -> h
        .headerFunction(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID, 
                   m -> m.getHeaders().getId()))
```

The constant `correlationId` is absolutely not good in the multi-threaded environment: different threads splits different files and send different lines to the same aggregator. So, with the `"1"` as correlation key you'd have always one group to aggregate and release. The default *sequence* behavior is to populate the original message `id` to the `correlationId`. Since you are not going to rely on the `applySequence` from the `FileSplitter` I suggest that simple solution to emulate that behavior.

As Gary pointed in his answer you need to think about custom `ReleaseStrategy` and send `FileSplitter.FileMarker` to the aggregator as well. The `FileSplitter.FileMarker.END` has `lineCount` property which can be compared with the `MessageGroup.size` to decide that we are good to release the group. The `MessageGroupProcessor` indeed has to filter `FileSplitter.FileMarker` messages during building the result for output.

Comment: You don't really need to compare the size; as long as it runs on a single thread, the END marker will be last.